# javascript to calculate the sum of Words

Tags: javascript, html

inside an html script i have inserted a src java script and created tables with id's which are labelled square1...e.g.`<td id="square0">apple;</td>.`
i want the javascript to display the sum of the alphabets in the word which are in the html file. like if  a is 1, b is 2, c is 3, d is 4...z is 26 then apple is 50, carrot is 75 and so on. i want the output to be like apple 50, carrot 75, yellow 92

the java script i tried was

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
...
...
var z = 26;
var addWord = new Array(1);
addWord[1] = "apple";
var square01 = 1 + 16 + 16 + 12 + 5;

function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    total += alphabet[word[i]];
    document.getElementById(square0).innerHTML;
}
}
```

many thanks
any help will do..

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need.

```
var word = "Apple"
var sum = 0;
word.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(function(alphabet) {
    sum += alphabet.charCodeAt(0) - 64;
});
console.log(sum);
```

Explanation in computers characters are considered as number constants with a specific value 
like 65 - "A" , 66 - "B" , 97 - "a" , 98 - "b".

What we did here is split the word into characters after turning it into capital letters.

"A" , "P" , "P" , "L" , "E"

And then we found out the value of each character by the charCodeAt(0) call . and then we substract 64 from it so that we get the value of character as per your requirements

A - > 65- 64 = 1 
B - > 66- 64 = 2

And so on.

Comment: The second parameter (`index`) can be omitted.

Comment: You could use `.forEach` here, since it's more semantic. You aren't actually mapping the array at all.

Comment: Even better than forEach, write a function `sum` that sums a list and use it with map. Less variables = good.

Comment: @RadekSlupik actually `.reduce` is for that but it is a lot more code `var sum = word.toUpperCase().split("").map(function(cur){
    return cur.charCodeAt(0) - 64;
}).reduce( function(prev, cur ) {
    return prev + cur;
});`

Comment: Here's an implementation using `reduce`: http://jsfiddle.net/m9yPj/ (I included `.match(/[A-Z]/g)` to only select alphas).

Comment: this works but only for 1 word apple, what if i wanted a list of words to be sorted...??  var word would allow me to input only 1 word.what if there was a html file with words in a table like <td id="square0">apple;</td> and var word would allow me to input only 1 word.what if there was a html file with words in a table like <td id="square0">carrot;</td>

Comment: Just use an iterator and iterate each word , or even better wrap this in a function and then call the function 

    String.prototype.getSum = function(word){
         var sum = 0;
         word.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(function(alphabet) {
         sum += alphabet.charCodeAt(0) - 64;
      });
    }


Now you can call 

"Apple".getSum(); 

To get sum or you can call the .getSum(); function on any String (Word)

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the sum of a word like this:

```
var word = "apple";
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
    sum += word.charAt(i).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96;
}
//sum is 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.charCodeAt()` to get the ASCII value of the character. You can subtract 96 from the result to get a = 1, b = 2...

eg:

```
var word = "apple";
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    sum += (word[i].charCodeAt() - 96);
}
console.log(sum);​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/En2Bh/4/)

You'll have to do some checking if you want to handle upper case letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Abhishek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708007/711085) is more readable, but this is how to do it with `reduce`; it's slightly shorter but the javascript syntax makes it unclear that `0` is the initial value of `sum`:

```
'Apple'.toUpperCase().split('').reduce(
    function(sum,letter){ return sum + letter.charCodeAt(0)-64 },
    0
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for letters "a".."z":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcAlpha() {
            var word = document.getElementById("square0").childNodes[0].data;
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i=word.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                sum += (word.charCodeAt(i) - 96);
            }
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=sum;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table><tr><td id="square0">apple</td></tr></table>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <button onclick="calcAlpha()">calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Abhishek That's a bit harsh.

Comment: wow...this was what i was looking for,....cool..i dont know what to say..but thankyou